# Can Firebase users created without a password still sign in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In a scenario where a new Firebase user is created without a password, could the user sign in using just their email address (passing a null/empty string as the password)?    Or does Firebase reject all attempts to authenticate with email + password when no password is specified in the user auth object?

The Firebase Admin SDK docs are clear that `password` is an optional property for `createUser()`,     but the [Password Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) docs don't appear to specify Firebase's behavior when the user was created without a password.   It would also be interesting whether an email link authentication (only) strategy can be enforced by leaving and/or setting a user's password as `undefined`, but this also doesn't appear to be explicitly called out in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).

Presumably Firebase rejects the email/password auth attempts, creating a de facto requirement for email link authentication (supported [anecdotally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778372/firebase-admin-how-to-create-user-with-passwordless-signin)), but any suggested links to Google authored docs would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication users are associated with one or more providers, and many of those providers don't need the user profile to have an associated password. For example: if you sign into Firebase with your Facebook account, the Firebase Authentication profile will not have an associated password. This applies to most providers, as in most cases the password is stored elsewhere (Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Microsoft, etc), or ephemeral (email-link, phone auth).